# jQueryUI Button on a form to be default button on hitting Enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a jQueryUI button on a form (not a modal dialog).  I want it to be fired when the user hits the Enter key.  How can I do this?  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="loginButtonInner">Login</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#loginButtonInner").button(getButtonOptions("ui-icon-unlocked", true));
    $("#loginButtonInner").button("option", "disabled", true);
    $("#loginButtonInner").unbind("click");
}

....

if (userNameValid && passwordValid)
    {       
        $("#loginButtonInner").button("option", "disabled", false);
        $("#loginButtonInner").unbind("click").bind("click", function () { authenticateUser(); return false; });
    }
    else 
    {       
        $("#loginButtonInner").button("option", "disabled", true);
        $("#loginButtonInner").unbind("click");
    }
```

Currently, I have to tab to reach the button via the keyboard or click via the mouse.

I searched for solutions online, but they all point to a modal dialog form button .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a key listener to your form elements and watch for the Enter key, then trigger the click from your button:

```
$(yourform).find('*').keypress(function(e) {
    if ( e.which == 13 ) { // 13 is the code for Enter key
        e.preventDefault();
        $(yourbutton).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys!  I'll try both these options!  Much appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [jQuery.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) function.
For example:

```
 $("#loginButtonInner").focus();
```

Will cause the element with ID of loginButtonInner to receive focus.  So when you press enter, if that element is a button it will be pressed.

Update: I tried it with a jQueryUI button and it works fine.